# Export to environment from script with ease

Tags: bash

I have dozens of scripts all starting with this top line and invoking a bash copy like:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

that do useful things. I'd like a line to call a function quite like:

```
settoplevel LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/$USER/libsherenow
```

where `settoplevel` is a function. A function inside the script is fine.  And this would make it a top level value, just like typing `export this=this` in the command line!

When you sit and write programs, it's convenient to be at the top level in bash and tiring to endlessly emit `export {whatever}` hundreds of times.

There must be a work around for this, isn't there?  There must be a way to make `export foo=bar` easy to do without typing it endlessly.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, if it is a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the dot `.` or `source` command:

```
. file-that-sets-LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or, if you like typing:

```
source file-that-sets-LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If the file contains:

```
...
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then these commands read the script (found by doing a search on PATH, but the file only needs to be readable; it does not have to be executable) in the current shell environment, rather than in a sub-shell.

If this isn't the bulk of the solution to your problem, then you need to rewrite the question with less apologia and a clearer question.

Comment: Well, I have found the "source" command is an adequate way to achieve the functionality entirely. I made many variable assignments that handle the variable concepts in a group, then a source XXXX call makes the more pliable ones equal the almost fixed ones. Tnx

Comment: You can get quite convoluted scripts for setting the environment. I have a 414-line script that resets a suite of environment variables appropriately for some software that I used to work on (convoluted by having to deal with multiple different versions of the software).  I have a 60+ line script backed by a 300+ line Perl script and a configuration file that does another environment variable setting task (again convoluted by multiple versions of multiple pieces of software).

Comment: Thanks for the commants fellows. Now that I understand it more I see better ways to get the results I want then treat the environment variables roughly. I suppose this is why there is just so many sometimes in automake autoconf M4X whatever all that stuff is. Thank you